# Unable to register Express middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I'm trying to write a very basic piece of middleware for Express that checks to see if a user has some specified role required to access a resource. I have another piece of middleware that comes before this, which adds a user object to the request `req` for every route requiring authentication (and subsequent authorization).

As such, I define the authorization middleware like this:

```
_ = require('lodash');

function authorize(req, res, next, roles){
    // check to see if user has one of the allowed roles
    if(_.contains(roles, req.user.role)){
        req.authorized = true;
        return next();
    }

    // otherwise, pass an error
    return next(new Error("Unauthorized"));
}
```

Every user object has a property called `role` on it, so I use `_.contains(roles, req.user.role)` to figure out whether or not the allowed roles contain the user's assigned role.

However, when I do this, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'role' of undefined` as soon as I start my Express server. This seems very weird to me, because I have not even made a request, and so of course `req.user` will be undefined until then.

Is there a way around this?

---

Example of how I use this middleware:

```
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/protected/:id', authorize(['ADMINISTRATOR', 'MANAGER', 'OWNER']), controllers.protected.retrieve);
```

Comment: Can you show us where you're adding the middleware? If I had to guess you're adding it as `authorize()` instead of `authorize`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I have update my question. Do you think I have to pass all of the parameters (i.e., req, res, next) to my middleware in the routing in order to get this to work? Thanks for your help

Comment: No, you need to pass _a function_ inside rather than call it, if that's too abstract for your current JS - wrap it in a (function(){ return authorize(....); })

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum could you explain why it is that I need to do it like this (perhaps in an answer below)? What you've suggested does the trick, but I don't exactly understand why it's necessary.

Comment: It almost seems like this middleware isn't even getting executed now, which is strange.

Comment: Because passing a function is what you need instead of invoking it, you don't want to _call_ the authorize function when you're declaring your middleware, you want to _pass_ it so that the code in express can later call it when it chooses to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register the route with

```
router.get(
    '/protected/:id',
    authorize(['ADMINISTRATOR', 'MANAGER', 'OWNER']),
    controllers.protected.retrieve
)
```

the `authorize` method gets executed straight away by `authorize(...)` with the `['ADMINISTRATOR', ...]` array being passed as the `req` param. Hence it is called as soon as you run the code and dies on user object not being present. Even if it didn't die on that, it wouldn't work as intended. You are mixing a *middleware* and a *factory* function together.

[Express middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html) is a function with a `(req, res, next)` signature, that you don't execute yourself. You need to pass a **reference** to such a middleware function and Express itself executes it on the request when needed, i.e.:

```
function authorize(req, res, next) {
    ...
};
router.get('/protected/:id', authorize, ...);
```

A parametrized middleware function, as in your case, can be easily created by splitting up to a *factory* and a *middleware* function:

```
// a factory function to create authorization middleware functions for given roles
function authorize(roles) {
    // create and return an actual authorization middleware function
    // to handle requests using the roles given when created
    return function(req, res, next) {
        if(_.contains(roles, req.user.role)){
            req.authorized = true;
            return next();
        }
        return next(new Error("Unauthorized"));
    }
}

router.get(
    '/protected/:id',
    authorize(['ADMINISTRATOR', 'MANAGER', 'OWNER']),
    controllers.protected.retrieve
)
```

Comment: Very thoroughly explained. I hope that this will help someone besides me!